# UWP: Button to Launch Windows Explorer with Folder set to the "App's Local Data Folder"

Tags: c#, uwp

Is it possible in UWP to launch file explorer with the current app's "local data folder"?

First I'm wondering how to invoke Explore or similar File Exploring Apps from UWP application.

Second, I'm wondering how to set the directory of the file explorer to the Current App's Local Data Folder. My goal is to have a `Button.Click` event handler invoke it.

Comment: I commented below but just for your visibility, I would recommend against doing this. Why would you want the user to be able to access the file structure of your apps local state?

Comment: It can be used as a private documents folder that’s only accessible by your app.

Comment: That's true, however, you're also going to potentially expose your user to other parts of your application's data that you don't want them to access, for example, they could accidentally delete any application settings that you may use.

Comment: That’s ok with me... my data files are xml and I encourage manual editing.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use `Launcher`'s `LaunchFolderAsync` method:

```
await Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . If that solved your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick mark below the arrows :-) . Happy coding!

Comment: It's cant use in mobile that the Explorer cant open it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only standard way. It is possible that Mobile explorer does not have this functionality implemented...

Comment: @lindexi Martin is right. There is no way to open the app's storage location on mobile due to the file explorer not having access to your apps local storage. 

The reason this works fine on desktop is because the folder is available.

However, for the OP, I would seriously recommend against doing this. Why would you want the user to be able to access the file structure of your apps local state?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Martin Zikmund's Answer:

```
...
using Windows.System;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace MyProject
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage2 : Page
    {
        ...

        async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync
                       (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
    }
}
```